# Error signing payload (JWT, jsrsasign)

Tags: javascript, rsa, jwt

I'm using `jsrsasign` to create JWT. Following the tutorial [here](https://github.com/kjur/jsrsasign/wiki/Tutorial-for-JWT-generation) I did the following:

```
// Header
var oHeader = {alg: 'RS256', typ: 'JWT'};
// Payload
var oPayload = {};
var tNow = KJUR.jws.IntDate.get('now');
var tEnd = KJUR.jws.IntDate.get('now + 1day');
oPayload.iss = "http://foo.com";
oPayload.sub = "mailto:mike@foo.com";
oPayload.nbf = tNow;
oPayload.iat = tNow;
oPayload.exp = tEnd;
oPayload.jti = "id123456";
oPayload.aud = "http://foo.com/employee";

var sHeader = JSON.stringify(oHeader);
var sPayload = JSON.stringify(oPayload);

var pbKey = KEYUTIL.getKey("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA+bg0doaHG2Pg/WplPgc0\nstTEdPyuNqD6jhvCOLrnq01R1M8QoBgiOmKhYUJrti/hybXSqp9uTp61dGPQ4KUU\nP7r4vjwzBYXzSUiS7YfCdWbX6bY8MW7eFXf3EADgNCi6NUBsTpOwKVyJuHFMxWFy\nR2Z9Pdw4gUuCrIqWaoGARIJ0Tkf5zT99C8AuwcJ46fZqPs6cNHtUaNu/CdXcgtPA\n3iXIXBZqlBkKPaNE6ATjtIUHftZhOx0aQLUDm2skbDmDre78R7GKNXPUWknfw7xV\nMpa93zYckxjce2MYNDbvmsK4gbzwm8zxYp+o0eMobOq7xe5hy/sRFbbHOZTqQWtp\nrwIDAQAB\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n");

var sJWT = KJUR.jws.JWS.sign("RS256", sHeader, sPayload, pbKey);

console.log(sJWT);
```

I generated the public key using the Ruby `jwt` gem as follows:

```
rsa_private = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.generate 2048
rsa_public = rsa_private.public_key

public_key = rsa_public.to_pem
```

I keep getting the following error while signing the payload:

```
"error"
"Uncaught Signature: unsupported public key alg: rsa (line 24)"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here's the link to JS Bin: http://jsbin.com/yehiyo/edit?js,console

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're doing wrong is simple. The code that you've written is correct. You cannot, however, sign a JWT with a *public* key. You'll need to use a *private* key for that. When you generated your key pair, you should have gotten a file that looks similar to the public key, but with `BEGIN PRIVATE RSA KEY`, etc.

That'll fix your issue. Best of luck.